# Unwanted line breaks in divs and spans

Tags: css, html

I'm using the following code to do some show / hide jquery effects:

```
<div id="toc_head1">
   <span id="plus1">
       +
   </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <h4>Overview</h4>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this is causing unwanted line breaks between the + symbol and the header text, even when this is added to my .css

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

How do I keep the plus symbol on the same line as the header?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h1~h6` elements are [**`block`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) elements, which means that they take the entire width of their container.

You have to use `display: inline-block` to make them stay on the same line (or `float`, or `display: inline`).

In your case, you might want to consider putting the `span` element inside your `h4` if it's semantically connected.

Comment: Like this?  <h4 style="display: inline-block">Overview</h4> -- didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsbin.com/gonekeba/1/edit - post more HTML for me to debug your case. (Also edited the answer with another alternative)